# How to enable STARTLS in maven Postman-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to send a mail during package phase. I am using mail host : smtp.gmail.com. Port: 587.

Getting error: Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

When we use 587 - we must enable STARTLS - but how can I enable using Maven Postman Plugin.

1. How to Enable STARTLS
2. what is the purpose of **mailAltConfig** tag in plugin configuration.

**BUILD ERROR:**

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.386 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-15T02:35:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/173M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. y2sm9686661pdm.31 - gsmtp ->
```

I have configured Postman Plugin as:

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>send a mail</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>send-mail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                                <from>donthadineshkumar@gmail.com</from>
                                <subject>My Project Documentation</subject>
                             <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                            <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost>
                            <mailport>587</mailport>
                            <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>
                            <mailuser>donthadineshkumar</mailuser>
                            <mailpassword>*my password*</mailpassword>
                           <htmlMessageFile>src/main/MailContent.html</htmlMessageFile>
                                <receivers>
                                        <receiver>donthadineshkumar.ddk@gmail.com</receiver>
                                </receivers>
                                <fileSets>
                                        <fileSet>
                                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main</directory>
                                                <includes>
                                                        <include>**/*.pdf</include>
                                                </includes>
                                        </fileSet>
                                </fileSets>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hey, did you solve this issue? Could you please post the answer if you did?

Answer (score 0):

if i am not using ssl and using 567 port i am facing the same issue as you. 
To solve this I used
`<mailssl>true</mailssl>
<mailport>465</mailport>`
and i was successful