# SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.57 issue while performing email configuration using POM.xml file

Tags: java, maven, email, pom.xml, starttls

I am using following plugin in POM.xml file for sending reports on email after completion of test execution. But getting following issue - SMTP: got response code 530, with response:

> 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail.

I checked some of solutions and it is advised to set property

```
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"),
```

but as I am setting configurations in POM not able to understand what tag should be used to set starttls as true.

plugin set in POM for email:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>

            <id>send a mail</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>send-mail</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>true</inherited>

            <configuration>
                <!-- From Email address -->
                <from>emailname@in.health.com</from>

                <!--  Email subject -->
                <subject>Test Automation Report</subject>

                <!-- Fail the build if the mail doesnt reach -->
                <failonerror>true</failonerror>

                <!-- host -->
                <mailhost>smtp.office365.com</mailhost>
                <!-- port of the host -->
                <mailport>587</mailport>
                <mailssl>false</mailssl>

                <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>

                <!-- Email Authentication(USername and Password) -->
                <mailuser>emailname@in.health.com</mailuser>
                <mailpassword>password</mailpassword>

                <receivers>
                    <!-- To Email address -->
                    <receiver>emailName@in.health.com</receiver>
                </receivers>

                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <!-- Report directory Path -->
                        <directory>C://Users//narayan//git//com.rxcorp//PlaftformAutomation//test-output</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <!-- Report file name -->
                            <include>customized-emailable-report.html</include>
                        </includes>
                        <!-- Use Regular Expressions like **/*.html if you want all the html files to send-->
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I believe this question was answered in this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054411/how-to-enable-startls-in-maven-postman-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054411/how-to-enable-startls-in-maven-postman-plugin)

Comment: I tried that solution, but not working for me. It coming as : Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:465: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 465: Connection timed out: connect